# Does not break word into parts for a new paragraph

Tags: line-breaking, typewriter

When I use `\texttt{}`, it does not break it into parts for new paragraph. Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be very helpful :)

Comment: Maybe you want `{\ttfamily Whatever\par Whatever else}`?